# How to headed chrome/chromium with Xvfb on lambda running puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, aws-lambda, chromium, puppeteer, xvfb

I need to get "headfull" chrome / chromium running with XvFB on Lambda running puppeteer as i am using extension for testing.
I have taken the below from the Nightmare lambda pack which installs Xvfb and puts it into the tmp folder and has a node 4.3 dependency.
var binaryPack = require('./lib/bootstrap/nightmare-lambda-pack'); // WIP: should be require('nightmare-lambda-pack')
var Xvfb = require('./lib/bootstrap/xvfb');
I have used the chrome-aws-lambda package which combines puppeteer and comes with a compressed chromium build which has a node 8.10 dependency
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
I can execute all this but for some reason i can only get it to work on headless.
Could someone give an help?